# Mysql polygon between multiple coordinates

Tags: javascript, mysql, google-maps, coordinates, polygon

[image]
I have 4 points on the map(latitude, longitude), there can be a more.
And I need to build a MySQL POLYGON with 10 Kilometers wide between these points.
As you see from the picture - I have blue line, and I need a polygon (green outline).

My first thought was to create two separate points for each given point.
For example:

1. Given 1st point(Bremen)
2. calculate 5km right and add a point,
       calculate 5km left and add a point.

Logic is simple.
BUT the problem is - I don't know what to calculate(right,top,bottom,left), i need some kind of angle, but I am stuck here.

I just need an algorithm, no need for a full code example.

function in javascript i tried:

```
var meters = 10000 / 2;
var my_lat = 52.51978;
var my_long = 13.388211;

// number of km per degree = ~111km (111.32 in google maps, but range varies
  /*  between 110.567km at the equator and 111.699km at the poles) */
// 1km in degree = 1 / 111.32km = 0.0089
// 1m in degree = 0.0089 / 1000 = 0.0000089
var coef = meters * 0.0000089;

var new_lat = my_lat + coef;

// pi / 180 = 0.018
var new_long = my_long - coef / Math.cos(my_lat * 0.018);
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the surrounding polygon? There might be an easier way to achieve what you are trying to do.

Comment: Maybe route boxer can be useful: https://github.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/tree/master/routeboxer